# Display number pad for user in html input fields when the type is text for mobile devices in the following special scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

The following web page will be accessed from a mobile device. Currently I have added comma separators for number input fields, but I have to set the input type to text for the comma separation procedure. Doing so will show an alphanumeric keypad to the end user on the mobile browser. Is there a way to display a numeric keypad to the end user while performing the comma separation on input?

**Method I tried for comma seperation**

```js
 $('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

    // skip for arrow keys
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  
    // format number
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
      ;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="f1qs3" class="form-control number" placeholder="Enter Value">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try input type `tel` for mobile devices

```
<input type="tel" id="f1qs3" class="form-control number" placeholder="Enter Value">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `pattern="\d*"` attribute to your input:

```
<input type="text" id="f1qs3" class="form-control number" placeholder="Enter Value" pattern="\d*">
```

This should make a keypad appear on mobile devices and should not affect your comma separation method.